# Unresolved external symbol on non-inline function body

Tags: c++, static-libraries

These type of errors are well discussed on SO and many other places, yet, I couldnt find a solution to my particular case.

Basically, I have made a static library project in my solution to seperate some functionality, and reference it in my current project. When I try to call a function from the library, i got this notorious linker error. I think there are no problems in setting up the project (references, dependencies etc.) .

First, I will give some minimal example of what I am working on ( there are some third party classes  )

```
//FileReader.h
    class IBKFileReader{

    public:
        virtual ~IBKFileReader() {} ;
        virtual void readFile(std::string fileName, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pointCloud ) = 0 ;

    };

    class XYZFileReader : public IBKFileReader
    {
    public:
        virtual void readFile(std::string fileName, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pointCloud )
        {
        }
```

And in my code, I call readFile function on a IBKFileReader object polymorphically.
And, this part is ok, without any errors, it compiles, links and runs.

However, when I move the body of the readFile function to a .cpp file and implement it there 
(with the same signature hopefully, i copy pasted) , I got the unresolved external symbol error.  This is the header of the function in .cpp file.

```
void XYZFileReader::readFile(std::string fileName, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pointCloud )
```

It seems that implementing the function body inline in the header file, and implementing in some seperate file makes a difference.

What do you think of this issue? Has anybody experienced something similar to this? I hope I am not missing out something obvious.

EDIT:
This is the error log i get:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl XYZFileReader::readFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class boost::shared_ptr<class pcl::PointCloud<struct pcl::PointXYZ> >)" (?readFile@XYZFileReader@@UEAAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$shared_ptr@V?$PointCloud@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@pcl@@@boost@@@Z)
```

EDIT:
I may have caused some misunderstanding. 
FileReader.h and FileReader.cpp is in static library project. I didnt do more than just implementing the function in the cpp file, definitions and such are still there.
In the same solution, in another project I reference to this project.

I am not getting the linker error when compiling the static lib, but when I am using it.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please paste the error itself - it's as equally important as everything else you mentioned in the question.

Comment: I think you'e not **linking** the object file from the compiled .cpp file you moved the function to with the rest of your program (assuming you're compiling said-cpp file, which at this point is still an unknown on our side). posting the link line for your project (i.e. the final link line of your Makefile) would likely confirm/squelch this.

Comment: @WhozCraig The compiled output of the library project is .lib file, and I add it to my second project's linker input settings. I couldnt get what you mean by "move the function with the rest of your program" . I just implement the function in a .cpp file in library project.

Comment: @bahti its a static lib? Am I correct this is with a Visual Studio project ? If so, check your project dependencies in the solution, and in particular make sure link library dependencies is *enabled* after setting the dependency of your project to be dependent on the lib. if you do that, you shouldn't need to add the explicit .lib to your linker line and the solution should just build on its own.

Comment: Yeah, actually I did that in the very beginning. But, then after getting this errors, I thought VS2010 could have done something wrong, then I added it manually too.

Answer (score 0):

A member function that is defined inside its class member list is called an inline member function. Try moving the member definition out of the class definition.

```
class XYZFileReader : public IBKFileReader
{
public:
    virtual void readFile(std::string fileName, 
                          pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pointCloud);
};

void XYZFileReader::readFile(std::string fileName, 
                             pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pointCloud) {}
```

Comment: Yes, actually my problem is that. Defining the function inline is ok, but when I define the function out of the class, I got the linker error.